# Update Navbar css properties when section within viewport

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [React Intersection Observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer) to see if a section is within viewport.

This function gets called from an external "section" component. When it gets called... I want it to change the :active state in my "Navbar" component, so for example if i'm scrolled in view of the AboutSection, the navbar link will change color.

```js
// when component within view, do this
export const inView = (section) => {
  console.log(`${section} section is in view`);
};
```

This is the Navbar component

```js
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Link from "@mui/material/Link";
import "../App.css";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <Box
      component="div"
      id="navbar"
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center",
        width: "300px",
        position: "fixed",
        top: "0",
        p: 1,
        boxShadow: 5,
        borderRadius: 2,
        backgroundColor: "primary.main",
        mt: 2,
        animationName: "intro",
        animationDuration: "6s",
        zIndex: "1000",
        "& .nav-link": {
          padding: 1,
          textDecoration: "none",
          color: "primary.light",
        },
        "& .nav-link:hover": {
          color: "secondary.main",
          transform: "scale(1.1)",
          transition: "ease-in 0.2s",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Link href="#home" className="nav-link">
        Home
      </Link>
      <Link href="#about" className="nav-link">
        About
      </Link>
      <Link href="#talents" className="nav-link">
        Talents
      </Link>
      <Link href="#contact" className="nav-link">
        Contact
      </Link>
    </Box>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

This is a snippet within a section component

```js
const HeroSection = () => {
 // react-intersection-observer functionality
  const elementRef = useRef(null);
  const isOnScreen = useOnScreen(elementRef);
  if (isOnScreen) inView("Hero"); // calls the function described
}
```

I hope this makes sense :/

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing the `:active` state I think it might be easier to do a class based setup (if the CSS is in your control). For example, you can say if the element has `.active` (instead of `:active`) then apply some styles. Adding a class to the element would be easier imo.